# What's the best way to share a secured internal WebMethod service endpoint across multiple pages in a .NET webforms application?

Tags: .net, webforms, webmethod

I've got a .NET Webforms application which requires a logged in Active Directory user, and I'd like to let the user write some info in a textbox and have autocomplete functionality for that.  I'm currently using jQuery's autocomplete method, which works fine, but I'm having a problem with how the autocomplete data options are supplied.

There are multiple pages in this application, and I'd like to offer that same autocomplete textbox on all the pages, so naturally I'm trying to make sure as much of the question markup and the data hosting are shared.

Using a .asmx web service is the natural solution for providing the autocomplete data, but I'm not able to access the currently logged in user's identity that way, and I need to know verify their specific username because the information returned to the autocomplete box is restricted to certain users.

I can use a WebMethod for this, but it has to be placed on each page, creating an unwanted duplication of code.

Furthermore, if it was at all possible it would be best to have the service for providing the autocomplete data hosted outside of the project entirely, because there are multiple projects I'd like to have hitting this common service, but I don't have a way of passing in the currently logged in user's Windows credentials to that service without hitting the project's server-side first.

Comment: I am assuming your webforms application is hosted on IIS. Set the authentication to Windows. Now when the user accesses your asp.net webforms site he will be automatically authenticated(assuming everything is on the same domain) which gives you the user context you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, it's running on IIS and I'm currently using basic authentication to require an Active Directory login.  So actually having the user be logged in isn't the issue, it's where I'm able to access the information about the logged in user.  Do you think switching to Windows authentication would change that?